# Como fazer um contador com ajuste de velocidade em javascript para simular o tempo de jogo

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma simulação de jogo de futebol, e preciso de uma função para contar o tempo até 45;

O que fiz deu certo, mas é muito rápido, queria ter a possibilidade de controlar a velocidade, por exemplo, velocidade 1 conta devagar, velocidade 2 mais rápido e assim por diante.

Fiz com loop:

```js
var tempo = 0;

function TempoDeJogo() {
  while (tempo < 45) {
    tempo++;
    console.log(tempo);
  }
  console.log("Fim de Jogo");
}
TempoDeJogo();
```

Só que nesse que fiz, a contagem até 45 é praticamente instantânea, quero poder ajustar essa velocidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternando a resposta do @AugustoVasques, poderiamos usar recursão e adotar algum parâmetro (número) para a função para definir um tempo de atraso e assim controlar a velocidade de execução.

Vamos supor os atrasos `3`, `2` e `1` (rápido, médio e devagar), e podemos usar esses valores e definir um intervalo de tempo até a função `TempoDeJogo` ser invocada na recursão.

```js
var tempo = 0;

function TempoDeJogo(atraso) {
  // verificação de segurança
  if (![1,2,3].includes(atraso)) atraso = 1 
  
  // divisão diminuir o atraso quanto maior for o valor de "atraso" (mais rápido)
  atrasoFinal = 1 / atraso

  const tempoAtrasoEmMs = atrasoFinal * 1_000 // tempo de atraso em ms

  if (tempo < 45) {
    tempo++;
    console.log(tempo);
    
    // chama a função TempoDeJogo novamente com o mesmo parâmetro
    return setTimeout(() => TempoDeJogo(atraso), tempoAtrasoEmMs) // delay para executar a recursão
  }
  console.log("Fim de Jogo");
}


TempoDeJogo(3) // executa rápido
// TempoDeJogo(2) // executa normalmente
// TempoDeJogo(1) // executa devagar
```

Answer (score 2):

Use em conjunto [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) e [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

- `setInterval()` cria um cronometro, retornado um id para esse cronometro, repetindo a execução de uma função continuamente dentro de intervalo de tempo especificado de milissegundos.
- `clearInterval()`cancela uma ação cronometrada e repetitiva que foi previamente estabelecida por uma chamada para `setInterval()`.

Basta poucas modificações para adequar o seu código:

```js
let tempo = 0;
let id = 0;

function TempoDeJogo() {
  //Ao invés de um loop faça uma verificação cada vez que função for chamada.
  if (tempo < 45) {
    tempo++;
    console.log(tempo);
    return;                      //Após a ação saia da função.
  }
  clearInterval(id);             //Finaliza o cronometro identificado por id.
  console.log("Fim de Jogo");
}

id = setInterval(TempoDeJogo, 1000);   //Inicializa o cronometro para chamar TempoDeJogo() a cada 1s.
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, valeu!