# Concatenação de valores do input JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, concatenação-de-string

Na aula de for ele nos pedem para montarmos um contador usando For ou While.
Eu tentei fazer a contagem no node.js com números fixos e funcionou, mas no site usando `<input type="number">`, o resultado deu valores concatenados infinitos, fazendo o site até parar de rodar. Tentei primeiro com `For` e depois com `While`, ambos deram errado.

```
function verificar() {
    var start = document.getElementById('begin')
    var finish = document.getElementById('end')
    var pass = document.getElementById('step')
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    var result = ''

    while (start.value <= finish.value) {
    console.log(start.value += pass.value)
   }
```

Eu vi outra resposta que ensinava a corrigir esse problema quando utilizamos `prompt`, mas gostaria de saber se dá pra resolver mesmo usando `input`.

Comment: Veja se o ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434117/137387 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510386/137387

Comment: seu loop (while) não muda o valor, pega sempre a mesma coisa (`start.value` por exemplo), logo vai ficar em um loop infinito.. preciso por os valores em variáveis que possa modificar, por exemplo algo assim `for(cont=start.value; cont<finish.value;cont++)`

Answer (score -2):

A condição do laço está incorreta. No seu código, a condição start.value <= finish.value sempre avaliará como true enquanto start.value e finish.value forem valores numéricos. Isso significa que o laço será executado indefinidamente. Para corrigir isso, você precisa alterar a condição para current <= finish.value, onde current é a variável de laço que você está usando para armazenar o valor da iteração atual.

A variável de laço não está sendo incrementada em cada iteração. No seu código, você está usando o operador += para aumentar o valor de start.value pelo valor de pass.value em cada iteração. No entanto, isso não é a forma correta de incrementar a variável de laço. Em vez disso, você deve usar a instrução current += pass.value para incrementar current em pass.value.

O codigo ficaria algo desse tipo:

`function verificar() { var start = document.getElementById('begin') var finish = document.getElementById('end') var pass = document.getElementById('step') var res = document.getElementById('res') var result = ''`
`var current = start.value; while (current <= finish.value) { res.innerHTML += current + '<br>'; current += pass.value; } }`